# How do I pass bindings to sqlite3 in Rust?

Tags: c++, sqlite, rust, ffi

I'm trying to pass a binding to sqlite3 via FFI. sqlite3 was compiled to a sqlite3.dll separately and loaded by `#[link(name = "sqlite3")]`

**ext.rs**

```rust
pub fn sqlite3_prepare_v3(db: *mut sqlite3, zSql: *const c_char, nByte: c_int,
                              prepFlags: c_uint, ppStmt: *mut *mut sqlite3_stmt, pzTail: *mut *const c_char) -> c_int;
pub fn sqlite3_bind_text(stmt: *mut sqlite3_stmt, w: c_int, b: *const c_char, n: c_int,
                             f: Option<c_int>) -> c_int;
pub fn sqlite3_step(stmt: *mut sqlite3_stmt) -> c_int;
pub fn sqlite3_column_text(stmt: *mut sqlite3_stmt, iCol: c_int) -> *const c_uchar;
```

**main.rs**

```rust
unsafe {
    let mut pointer = null_mut();
    println!("{}", sqlite3_prepare_v3(self.sqlite, CString::new("SELECT ?;".to_owned()).unwrap().as_ptr(), -1, 0, &mut pointer, null_mut()));
    println!("{}", sqlite3_bind_text(pointer, 1, CString::new("hello".to_owned()).unwrap().as_ptr(), -1, Some(SQLITE_TRANSIENT)));
    println!("{}", sqlite3_step(pointer));
    println!("{}", CStr::from_ptr(sqlite3_column_text(pointer, 0) as *const i8).to_str().unwrap());
}
```

and the result went:

```
0
0
100
 <- Note it's empty here, and how do I get 'hello' instead?
```

When I try this on c++, like this:

```cpp
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
cout << sqlite3_prepare_v3(
    ppdb,
    "SELECT ?;",
    -1,
    0,
    &stmt,
    NULL
) << endl;
cout << sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "hello", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) << endl;
cout << sqlite3_step(stmt) << endl;
cout << sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
```

I get

```
0
0
100
hello
```

Comment: **Did you read the documentation of [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) and of [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/)** and the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) ? Notice that C++11 (see [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) ...) is not the same as C (or as Rust). Read also the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...) and linker (e.g. [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)...)

Comment: For your next question, please provide some [mre]. See also [rusqlite](https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite)...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Hi and thanks!  I found the sqlite3 doc does mention the string format at[Binding Values To Prepared Statements](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html#:~:text=The%20third%20argument), and it corresponds to the *char format in msvc's c++, and so does it in rust's cstring: [std::ffi::CString - Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html). Looks like they are compatible. Is this still related to the compilers? I'm new to this field, my bad, haha.

Comment: As you seem to be aware that C and C++ are different languages, please do not add C tag if you program in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using

```rust
println!("{}", sqlite3_prepare_v3(self.sqlite, b"SELECT ?;\0".as_ptr() as *const i8, -1, 0, &mut pointer, null_mut()));
println!("{}", sqlite3_bind_text(pointer, 1, b"google\0".as_ptr() as *const i8, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT));
```

However, I don't exactly know why, lol